# How To improve wpf user control performance?

Tags: wpf, performance, mvvm, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a usercontrol, and when I have lots of that in a window, it takes long time to get loaded.
Will it get better if I change it to a customcontrol or maybe a `DataTemplate` with a class and attached properties?
any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited:**

this is my control:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Pouyansoft.WPF.MVVM.Control.Common.View.DataGridSelectorControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    x:Name="dataGridSelector"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DataCollection.Source}" x:Key="theSource"/>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                                 BorderThickness="1" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>       
   <DataGrid x:Name="grd" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource theSource}}" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"   
             PreviewKeyDown="grd_PreviewKeyDown"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
             behavior:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" 
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  
             GridLinesVisibility="Vertical">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and some code in the code behind.(and actually  all the other control has the same behavior)

Comment: Please show us the xaml and code or explain what is slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, don't use `DynamicResource` use `StaticResource` -

use

```
ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"
```

in place of

```
ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"
```

Second thing is to check for binding errors in your Output window, try and fix as many as you can.

Also, I don't see any benefit of using `CollectionViewSource` (as you are not doing any Sorting, Filtering, Grouping); If it's not necessary to use `CollectionViewSource`, you can directly bind the `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource` to your `DataCollection.Source`.

Comment: @ akjoshi :thanks for your warning about staticresource,but i changed usercontrol to customcontrol,and there is so much diffrence between them!!

Comment: @raha : yes UserControl and CustomControl are ment for different purpose and their implementations are very different.